# If the data type of the age variable is the object, I want to convert it to numeric. But I get an error like this in my model

Tags: data-analysis, categorical-data

these are the categorized form of age variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMMsV.png)

the code i wrote:

```
age_dict = {  "[0-10)" : 1,
              "[10-20)" : 2,
              "[20-30)" : 3,
              "[30-40)" : 4,
              "[40-50)" : 5,
              "[50-60)" : 6,
              "[60-70)" : 7,
              "[70-80)" : 8,
              "[80-90)" : 9,
              "[90-100)" : 10
           }
    ["age_Ordinal"] = df_age.age.map(age_dict)
    df_age
```

I get an error like this in my model:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[50-75)'
but there is no age range (50-75) in the variable.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with `age_dict`. I'm guessing you're trying to index into age_dict using the key `"[50-75)"` and ignoring a KeyError

Comment: Unfortunately. I don't have a category to add as [50-75) in age variable